# Execute makensis from python on linux

Tags: python, nsis

I have compiled makensis on linux. It works great when executed from a bash shell like this.

```
makensis /path/to/setup.nsi
```

I would like to execute it using a python script. I have tried the following:

```
#using the symlink in /usr/bin
subprocess.call("makensis setup.nsi")

#absolute path to makensis executable
subprocess.call("/usr/share/makensis/makensis setup.nsi")

#Change directory
os.chdir("/usr/share/makensis")
subprocess.call("makensis setup.nsi")
```

I have also tried passing the cwd arg to subprocess.call.

In all of these cases makensis is unable to find its dependencies. It is looking in /usr/bin/ and throwing this error:

```
Error: opening stub "/usr/bin/Stubs/zlib"
```

I am not sure if this is a problem with my python script or the way makensis was compiled.  I am inclined to think it is the python script, since makensis works fine from the bash shell. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Edit:
This is the scons command I used to build nsis:

```
scons SKIPSTUBS=all SKIPPLUGINS=all SKIPUTILS=all SKIPMISC=all NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no PREFIX=/usr/share/ APPEND_CCFLAGS=-m32 APPEND_LINKFLAGS=-m32 install-compiler
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your scons command used to build NSIS...

Comment: Just to let you know, it is possible to cross compile the stubs and plugins on Posix now...

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the heads up. Do you have a link for the documentation?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of 'scons XGCC_W32_PREFIX=i686-w64-mingw32-' ( http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2985008&postcount=5 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use NSIS extensively, but I had never thought to try running it on a posix/unix platform.  In any event, I checked around (since I'm always interested in more NSIS configs), and found this link -- which specifically identifies your issue and includes resolution

http://wiki.koshatul.com/Installing_Nullsoft_Scriptable_Installer_System_%28NSIS%29_on_BSD#Error:_opening_stub_.22.2Fusr.2Flocal.2Fbin.2FStubs.2Fzlib.22

> Remove the NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no if you have it from your
>   scons line, check the paths are all good for building as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had assumed that if that was incorrect it wouldn't work from the command line either.  I will try rebuilding it with different path options.

Comment: Using the scons command from that link did the trick. Thanks. Using the options in the link, you need to manually place Contrib, Include, Plugins, and Stubs folders into /usr/local/share/nsis.